# Starting a thread in a suspended state

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a class `TADE`. This class has a static method `addTST(...)` which saves a thread to a `std::map<std::string, std::thread>`.

I want to pause the thread right after I have created it (it is sufficient for what I want to do), but I don't know how threads work.

If someone knows a better way to save a thread without actually starting it, and only starting it if the respective function (which can be called `resumeTST(...)` or `startTST(...)`, etc), then I would be more than happy to know, but I would rather know more about pausing/resuming threads independently.

This is the current code for the `addTST(...)` function:

```cpp
template<typename Func, typename ...Args>
void TADE::addTST(std::string tst_id, Func func, Args ...args) {
    std::thread t(func, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // pause thread t
    TADE::tsts.insert(std::make_pair(tst_id, &t));
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to pause a running thread or do you rather want to defer starting it until a later time but save the functor and arguments?

Comment: Also which C++ standard version do you aim for?

Comment: Sounds like you maybe want to wait on a [std::condition_variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) ...?

Comment: If the thread has no work to do, isn't it going to pause anyway? If you didn't pause it, what would it do?! You write the code for this thread, why do you need to reach in from the outside and pause it?

Comment: @Homer512 I'm aming for C++17 and I would like to know how to pause a running thread.

Comment: If the launched threads cooperate, e.g. by checking a flag whether they should pause, it's easy enough and paddy's answer is a good start. If you want to pause threads at any moment without the threads themselves actively involved, you have to resort to platform-specific mechanisms like signals. Overall I advise against pausing threads in the first place as it is very easy to produce deadlocks. Better let threads terminate and then start new ones. But this all depends on the bigger picture of what you actually want to achieve

Comment: Pausing threads via correct synchronization is fine. Reasons why one might wish to do that instead of creating/destroying threads is that the latter is computationally expensive, whereas sleeping/waking (at the correct time) is lightweight. So when that's an important consideration you might prefer this. As always, the design depends on exactly what the program is supposed to do. There's no "right way", but there are definitely "common solutions".

Answer (score 4):

Some OS-level threading support allows a thread to be suspended upon creation (Windows, for example), but `std::thread` does not provide for this as far as I'm aware.

The basic way to achieve that is to use a `std::mutex`, which is held in a locked state by the creating thread. This is passed into the new thread, by whatever mechanism you normally pass data to a new thread. The thread service function then immediately tries to acquire a lock on that mutex. This will block, and the thread will go to sleep.

When it's time to wake up the thread, you simply unlock the mutex. The new thread will then acquire a lock and away it goes. But this is only really useful when you're creating one thread and/or you only want to run one thread at a time. Unless you want to maintain a separate mutex for each thread.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::mutex m;
    m.lock();

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int id = 0; id < 10; id++)
    {
        threads.emplace_back([id, &m]() {
            std::lock_guard guard(m);
            std::cout << "Thread " << id << " is alive!\n";
        });
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "Release the hounds!\n";

    m.unlock();
    for (auto& t : threads) t.join();
}
```

Possible output:

```
Release the hounds!
Thread 5 is alive!
Thread 6 is alive!
Thread 7 is alive!
Thread 8 is alive!
Thread 9 is alive!
Thread 4 is alive!
Thread 3 is alive!
Thread 2 is alive!
Thread 1 is alive!
Thread 0 is alive!
```

The more general approach is to use a semaphore (*i.e.* `std::condition_variable`), which is useful if you wish to wake a one or multiple threads repeatedly, or if you want to piggyback other kinds of control message to your thread(s) other than just "run". This approach is applicable when you are driving a pool of worker threads that batch-out tasks.

It should be noted that no matter what you do, `tsts.insert(std::make_pair(tst_id, &t));` is *not* okay! The identifier `t` is a local variable. You cannot store a pointer to it and then exit the function. Either store the `std::thread` by value (using `std::move` to push it into the container) or allocate/store it with a `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Thank you for the last note! Can you provide me with some code?

Comment: I added a toy example demonstrating the simple approach: multiple threads that can be woken up one at a time via a shared mutex. Only one thread runs at once in this case, because they maintain the lock until the thread exits.